# How can i speedup my password generation script in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, random, passwords

So i have a script that generates secure passwords with the `choice` module, but i find it really slow in the generation time and disk write speed (~0.4 Mo/s; for 1,000,000 passwords generated; 16 to 32 chars)

Have you any tips to make this script faster?

Also password generation is located in the `for mult in range(num_passwords)` loop

here is it:

```
import string, os, sys, random, time
from secrets import choice

#Requesting informations
#must be int
num_files = int(input("[INT] Number of files: "))
num_passwords = int(input("[INT] Number of codes: "))
num_bits_from = int(input("[INT] Number of bits (from): "))
num_bits_to = int(input("[INT] Number of bits (to): "))

#must be str
add_infos = str(input("[INT] Add additional infos in file? [1/0]: "))
folder_name = str(input("[STR] Folder name (create new): "))
file_prefix = str(input("[STR] File prefix: "))
file_extension = str(input("[STR] File extension: "))

#creating folder
os.mkdir(folder_name)

#User selects charlist or create a new one
#Default: chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
while True:
    print("Select a charlist:")
    print("1/ ASCII w/o specials")
    print("2/ ASCII w/ specials")
    print("3/ New charlist")
    charlistChoice = str(input("\n[INT] (1/2/3): "))
    if charlistChoice == "1":
        chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
        break
    elif charlistChoice == "2":
        chars = string.punctuation + string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
        break
    elif charlistChoice == "3":
        print("========")
        print("Please enter charlist on one line")
        print("Example: abcABC123?;!")
        chars = str(input("[CHARLIST]> "))
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid choice!")
        continue #Goes to the top of the while loop

input("press [ENTER] to generate")

#Charlist has been set, starting generation
print("Please wait, this can take a while")
print("========")

for mult in range(num_files): #For given number of files
    file_name = file_prefix + str(mult) + file_extension
    print("Generating", str(num_passwords), "passwords in", file_name, "...")

    if add_infos == "1": #if user requested to write add. infos in file
        currentFile = open(file_name, "w")
        currentFile.write("====Generation====\n")
        currentFile.write("bits per line (from): "+str(num_bits_from)+"\n")
        currentFile.write("bits per line (to): "+str(num_bits_to)+"\n")
        currentFile.write("total codes: "+str(num_passwords)+"\n")
        currentFile.write("====Start====\n")

        for x in range(num_passwords): #Generate WITH additionnal infos
            currentFile.write(str(x)+": "+''.join([choice(chars) for _ in range(random.randint(num_bits_from, num_bits_to))])+"\n")

    else: #Does not write additionnal infos in file
        currentFile = open(file_name, "w")

        for x in range(num_passwords): #Generate passwords with bits from int and to int
            currentFile.write(''.join([choice(chars) for _ in range(random.randint(num_bits_from, num_bits_to))])+"\n")

    currentFile.close()
    os.system("move "+file_name+" "+folder_name) #Closes and move file to folder, iterating again

#Generation completed

os.system("pause")
sys.exit(0) #Exits the program with code 0
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try generating fewer passwords?  Why do you need that many all at once?  Generate, say, 5,000 passwords and store them.  Remove them from the store when they are used, keeping track.  When the store drops below 3,000 passwords generate 2,000 more.  Adjust the number as needed.

Comment: @rossum But my idea with this script was originally to create a big wordlist (200+ Mb), with customizable chars and length, and even with your advice, the io speed is still slow :(